# Transfer counter variable from PHP to .JS file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass a counter variable that I made in my PHP script to my .JS file. I've read on here that the best way to do this is with JSON (I'm writing with JQuery), but I'm having a hard time getting it to work with what I have.

In my PHP, I apply my counter to a td class and then send it over via JSON. So:

```
….
<table>
<?php $counter = 0;?>
<?php while ($counter < 20) : ?>
<tr>
...
<td class="classname<?php echo $counter; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = <?php echo json_encode($counter); ?>;
</script>

<?php $counter++;
endwhile; ?>
</table>
…
```

Now in my .js file, I have the following line that tries to put the counter that I echoed into the CSS identifier:

```
  if...
  $('td.classname' + counter).text("Text gets displayed");/* Change text in td */}
```

Is this the wrong way to access the variable?

Comment: this question is probably more suited for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your code looks fine. But you did not tell us what it does wrong.

Comment: your script block is inside the while loop, so I would think that your resulting html would have 20 script blocks declaring `counter` with different values

Comment: MrOBrian.  That is what I'm going for.  I would like to give each TD it's own counter variable with different values.  Then, when I apply my IF statement in the JS, I'm able to alter the text in the TD and not every TD in the TR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of JSON since you are doing this on server side, just remove `json_encode` and `echo` the value which will assign it to js `counter`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: you may all want to put quotes around it so it is a string. var counter = "<?php echo $counter; ?>";

Comment: `$counter` is a integer. quotes not required.

Comment: I agree should not be a problem but he is using it as a string in his javascript code. But it looks the big problem is that he put it in the while loop.